# How low can Yarn container memory be set for hdfs map reduce in test?

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn, bigdata

I am setting up a hadoop single node environment for testing on a hardware that only has 4GB physical RAM, and using hadoop 2.6.0.

I've used just the basic configs suggested for such an environment. But I am now concerned that I probably should tweak the memory resource management in order to be able to run some map reduce examples.

I know there are a couple of settings to look at including java heap, and memory for map and reduce tasks. For a small scale test environment such as mine how low should/can I set the minimum, maximum container size for a modest map reduce task to function?

Particularly I am referring to:

```
yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb
yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb
```

After start-dfs and start-yarn, the free physical on the machine is well below 1 GB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work on a VM quite often and I have these settings in my yarn-site.xml:

```
  <property>
    <description>Max available memory on each data node.</description>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
    <value>4096</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <description>Max available cores data node.</description>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores</name>
    <value>8</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <description>Minimum allocation unit.</description>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
    <value>256</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <description>Max allocation unit.</description>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb</name>
    <value>4096</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <description>Minimum increment setting - set to same as min-allocation</description>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.increment-allocation-mb</name>
    <value>256</value>
  </property>
```

And this in mapred-site.xml -

```
 <!-- small cluster memory settings -->
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.map.memory.mb</name>
    <value>256</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb</name>
    <value>256</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <description>Application master allocation</description>
    <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb</name>
    <value>256</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.map.java.opts</name>
    <value>-Xmx204m</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.reduce.java.opts</name>
    <value>-Xmx204m</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <description>Application Master JVM opts</description>
    <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.command-opts</name>
    <value>-Xmx204m</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb</name>
    <value>50</value>
  </property>
```

I find these settings work pretty well on anything I run on my VM with Vm sized data volumes (ie, not too big!).

Comment: Thanks. I tried these settings, after start-dfs+yarn, I get a warning in the logs: `NodeManager configured with 4 G physical memory allocated to containers, more than 80% of the total physical memory available (3.7 G).` 
I probably have to reduce `yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb`.
The actual symptom I am dealing with in runnin a map-reduce example is this error:
`Error in instantiating YarnClient
Cannot initialize Cluster. Please check your configuration for mapreduce.framework.name and the correspond server addresses.`
The error persists before and after applying your settings.

Comment: The warning probably isn't worth worrying about on a VM environment. It sounds like there are a few other setting you are missing. Are you using a Hadoop distribution, eg Cloudera CDH? If you just want to play around with Hadoop you can grab a quickstart VM from Cloudera and it all works out of the box. Or, there are pretty good 'quickstart' setup instructions to build a VM in Clouderas documentation too.

Comment: Probably accepted the answer too soon.
I ran this example:
`hadoop jar mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.6.0.jar wordcount /user/WordCount.txt /user/output2`
and got this result:
`Container [pid=17656,containerID=container_145...] is running beyond virtual memory limits. Current usage: 192.2 MB of 256 MB physical memory used; 892.3 MB of 537.6 MB virtual memory used. Killing container.`

Comment: after increasing `mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb` and `yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb` to 512 the example mapred job was successful